# Jquery, calculate html table rows with same class?

Tags: jquery

I am building an invoice with grails, and for dynamical calculation I am using jquery.

I don't know, may be its not a good solution and I am not that fit in javascript. May be someone could help me, here we go:

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <g:sortableColumn style="width: 20px" property="id" title="${message(code: 'packet.id.label', default: 'Id')}" />
        <g:sortableColumn style="width: 10px" property="anzahl" title="${message(code: 'packet.anzahl.label', default: 'Anzahl')}" />
        <th><g:message style="width: 250px" code="packet.artikel.label" default="   Artikel    " /></th>
        <th><g:message code="packet.artikel.label" default="   Steuer in %   " /></th>
        <th><g:message code="packet.artikel.label" default="   Preis pro Stück in €  " /></th>
        <th><g:message code="packet.artikel.label" default="   Preis Gesammt in € " /></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <g:each in="${packetInstanceList}" status="i" var="packetInstance">
        <tr class="${(i % 2) == 0 ? 'odd' : 'even'}">
            <td><g:link controller="packet" action="show"  id="${packetInstance.id}">${fieldValue(bean: packetInstance, field: "id")}</g:link></td>
            <td><input name="q" class="st" type="text" style="background-color:transparent;border:0px solid white;" value="${fieldValue(bean: packetInstance, field: "anzahl")}" onclick="if (this.value=='Search') {this.value = '';}" readonly="true"/>
            <!--  ${fieldValue(bean: packetInstance, field: "anzahl")}    -->
            </td>
            <td nowrap>${fieldValue(bean: packetInstance, field: "artikel")}</td>
```

that creates a html with many rows with

```
        <tr class="even">
            <td><a href="/test/packet/show/17">17</a></td>
            <td><input name="q" class="st" type="text" style="background-color:transparent;border:0px solid white;" value="1,222" onclick="if (this.value=='Search') {this.value = '';}" readonly="true"/>
                <!--  1,222    -->
            </td>
            <td nowrap> Blueray,Arthouse </td>
            <td> <input type="text" style="background-color:transparent;border:0px solid white;" class="input-steuer" value="19"/> </td>
            <td> <input type="text" style="background-color:transparent;border:0px solid white;" class="input-value"  /> </td>
            <td> <input type="text" style="background-color:transparent;border:0px solid white;" class="output-value" readonly />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="odd">
            <td><a href="/test/packet/show/18">18</a></td>
            <td><input name="q" class="st" type="text" style="background-color:transparent;border:0px solid white;" value="100" onclick="if (this.value=='Search') {this.value = '';}" readonly="true"/>
                <!--  100    -->
            </td>
            <td nowrap> Blueray,Arthouse </td>
            <td> <input type="text" style="background-color:transparent;border:0px solid white;" class="input-steuer" value="19"/> </td>
            <td> <input type="text" style="background-color:transparent;border:0px solid white;" class="input-value"  /> </td>
            <td> <input type="text" style="background-color:transparent;border:0px solid white;" class="output-value" readonly />
            </td>
        </tr>
            <td> <input type="text" style="background-color:transparent;border:0px solid white;" class="input-steuer" value="19"/> </td>
            <td> <input type="text" style="background-color:transparent;border:0px solid white;" class="input-value"  /> </td>
            <td> <input type="text" style="background-color:transparent;border:0px solid white;" class="output-value" readonly />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </g:each>
```

As you can see these rows have same classes.

Here is jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".input-value").keyup(function() {
        // var output = $(".output-value");
        var test = 0;

        $('.input-value').each(function() {
            var value = parseFloat($(this).val());
            var value3 = parseFloat($(".st").val());
            var value2 = parseFloat($(".input-steuer").val());

            //output.val(((value - value * value2/100)*value3).toFixed(2));
            score = ((value - value * value2/100)*value3);
            score = score.toFixed(2);
            //output.val(score);
            test+=score;
        });

        $(".output-value").val(test);
    });
});
```

This calculates only the first row and not each row, 
I´d like to have a output for every row
and sum of the all outputs, but I am not used to javascript...

It feels like it is simple, but not for me.

Thanks for your time

Comment: my output generates 00.810.81, which means the first value="1,222" and  class="input-steuer" value="19" are overwritten.

Comment: Hey man, sorry, I don't have the correct code with me now. However, the answer Jebin gives sounds right. The problem is that jQuery only sees one input. This is caused by using the same class or id. What Jebin suggests extracts all available elements and then you can loop trough them.

Comment: Props dude, good luck in further development!

Comment: aw :d, sorry, my first post in desperation...

Comment: Never mind, avoiding staring at my code is also the reason I'm here currently :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".input-value").keyup(function() {

    var value = parseFloat($(this).val());
    var value2;
    var value3;var temp=0;var temp1 = 0;
    $(this).parent().siblings().each(function() {
        if ($(this).children().hasClass('input-steuer')) {
            value2 = $(this).children().val();
        }
        if ($(this).children().hasClass('st')) {
            value3 = $(this).children().val();
        }
    });
    score = ((value - value * value2 / 100) * value3);
    $(this).parent().next('td').children('.output-value').val((score).toFixed(2));
    $('.output-value').each(function(){
        temp1 = $(this).val();        
        alert(temp1);
        if(temp1 == 'NaN' || temp1 == '') {
           temp1 = 0.0; 
        }
        temp = parseFloat(temp) + parseFloat(temp1); 
    });
    $('#wholesum').val(temp.toFixed(2));
});​
```

Have a nice day!

Comment: THIS IS PERFECT! I LOVE YOU! OMG, i´d never find .parent().siblings()

Comment: hmmm, i guess i´m pretty bad on it, id like to have one more element to a row, but it won't work, the element should have     score2 = (value * value3); and $('#wholesum2').val(temp2.toFixed(2)); as an answer, but if i add this in query and html, it won't show anything, i guess i did not understand what some function parent() and next() do :D

Comment: Update the fiddle which you posted yesterday with your new fields whatever you want and post it. Also the above comment is not so clear to me. Make it more elaborate.